# GIT GUI for solo project: Windows PC for development, but git + active, working project repo on a LAN headless linux server?

Tags: git, dvcs, smartgit

I just installed git for the first time for a solo project -- and now I don't know how I lived without version control for so long. I wanted to see if maybe a GUI would be helpful, but I have a problem...

- My development machine is running windows
- The project is on a headless linux server on the LAN
- Project directories are shared through samba and mapped as network drives on the windows pc
- I am the only one using this server, so there's no need to clone the repo to the windows pc
- If I use git through SSH none of this is a problem at all

The GUI git clients I've tried so far all assume I'm running git on the machine I install them on, though. If I try to operate on the linux-hosted repo with widnows-installed git, it's (not unexpectedly) slow as molasses and seems to have compatibility issues.

Is there any way to make this work for smartgit? Or any other decent client?

I did install gitweb, which seems nice enough to look through project history, but I can't actually 'do' anything with it.

**EDIT**: If I could maybe broaden this question and just ask for a word of advice on how to proceed, ie: suck it up and use Putty with something else for visualization, clone the repo and push/pull, or do something different like svick's X Server suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I'll be marking my own answer correct for clarity and not vanity, to hopefully help someone caught in a similar predicament. I hope no one will be offended.

As, a side note, after coming up with a working solution, I still ended up using SSH and a drive-mapped shared  linux directory for development, but it's useful to have a local place on the windows machine to put a working repo. GIT is just slow as molasses on windows for me no matter what, so I'll be using it that way as little as possible -- but that's just me.

If your bash-foo is weak like mine, webmin can help with the below. So here's what I ended up doing:

**Summary:**

- Web-based project (LAMP stack in my case)
- Solo developer
- 1 Windows pc used for development
- 1 headless linux server to host the stack and the project

**Purpose:**

- Set up a working repo locally on the windows PC to enable efficient use of git GUI clients, etc without having to make a whole working stack or commit and push to see what the hell just happened. PHP on windows sucks (*yes, yes, more than usual har har*), and so do a lot of other things.

**Solution upside:**

- No need to duplicate the LAMP stack on the windows machine, or screw with the database to have a working local repo
- Preview your changes in real-time without having to commit or push

**Solution downside:**

- Local (windows) repo only functional if computer is on the network
- You might see a bit of network latency due the loopty-loo nature of what's happening here

**Prerequisites:**

- Static or MAC based IPs for both the windows and linux machines
- git, BIND, Samba, Apache (or similar) on the linux box
- SSH client (Putty?), msysgit, git GUI of choice (gitextensions/smartgit/gitgui) on the windows box

**What to do:**

1. Set up a shared directory on the windows box for the repo
2. Mount this directory on the linux box
3. Point BIND to the linux box's own IP for your two domain (eg: myproject.lin and myproject.win) -- (apologies for the fake tlds, but use your own discretion here)
4. Make the linux box your dns resolver for either the windows box or your network router
5. Set up two domain-based servers in Apache (the ones above) and direct them to the appropriate locations (eg: '/mnt/windows-pc/myproject' and '/var/www/myproject')
6. Make sure your application configuration can map relative paths for obvious reasons
7. Samba-share the linux repo and maybe map it as a windows network drive for convenience
8. Clone your linux box's repo to the windows directory
9. Push changes as needed back to the linux shared project directory

To further complicate what probably hardly needed any explanation here is a (simplified) diagram:
[image: something to do with pants i thinks]

Comment: Oh god. That graphic. I can't plus one enough.

Answer (score 3):

> I am the only one using this server, so there's no need to clone the repo to the windows pc

Actually, it seems there is some need. If you want the repository to be as fast as if it was a local repo, the easiest option is to actually create a local repo.

Another option would be to install X Server on the Windows machine and use X tunneling over SSH to run the git GUI on the Linux server, but display it on Windows.

Comment: @Greg I agree with svick here - it's a good idea to clone it in, that's actually part of the beauty of DVCS. You can accomplish your goal _and_ still deploy to Apache, so not much would change except you'd push to the remote while getting all of the joys of the GUI clients you'd like to use.

Comment: @melee The major downside I see is that I'd have to both commit and push with every tiny change to preview what it did, unless I want to install Apache and PHP on windows -- which is unfortunately a nightmare of bugs and clobbered features. :(

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of DVCS is that you're getting an entire, local copy of the repo on your local machine. In the case of git, it's almost assumed that you're going to be cloning or (at the minimum) housing the repository locally.

Now, you've stated that it isn't ideal for you to clone it over, but the fact is that in order for the GUI to be effective, it's going to need to be running where the repo is locally.

Depending on your workflow/setup, this may or may not be feasible. Here's my suggestion:

1. Setup XAMPP on your local workstation, even if it is a huge time investment to get going.
2. Bring the repository in and add your Linux station as a remote, or (ideally) setup something like [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/wiki/)
3. Develop locally. Think of it as an "alpha" stage. You get additional benefits here - you can basically screw up your entire app and it won't be live. And your GUI!
4. `git push` to the remote repo, and ta-da, deployed.

Now, there's a few better ways to really get into this if you have the resources, and I've detailed them in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372916/git-workflow-with-wordpress-localhost-to-live/6373314#6373314). Again, if you have the flexibility to do something like this, I highly recommend it. If that's too radical, you might have to stay the course with what you're doing. Hope this helps.

PS: I'm a solo developer as well, and I put a LOT of time into my version control setup. It has paid off!

Comment: Hmmm... what if instead of duplicating the stack on the windows PC I just mount a network directory on the server and point apache to it on a different domain with BIND. Is that too weird? The server itself is strictly for development, so none of this is live.

Comment: effort++, haha - you could clone it and leave out the XAMPP part and just push it upwards. Honestly, it's super fast because you're really only pushing deltas

Comment: Yeah, I'm just brooding on having to change the paths in configs and more importantly deal with PHP on windows machine, which is a huge bag of suck. Not mention figuring out what to do with the database.

Comment: @Greg yeah, I understand. The project I inherited actually has the prod on IIS and the dev on LAMP and a CRAZY layout (like 44 nonsensical aliases) so it was annoying to setup.

Comment: Just so you know, I ended up going with the linux-mounted windows-pc network share, BIND, linux apache idea. Works okay, even with a little bit of latency. I'll try to make a habit to commit and push often, but this seems to work pretty well.

Comment: @Greg you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have a comparable configuration and I run a clone on the target Linux box.  However I also develop on the headless Linux box using ssh from Windows.  I'm running Xming on Win7/64.  So for this activity the Windows box is pretty much just an X-terminal.

I have installed gnome-terminal on the Linux box, because I'm not happy with either putty or the xmingw bash that runs in a Windows command window.

It ain't perfect, but it's proven to be workable.