# What is the best strategy to store in repository only changed files?

Tags: git

I have a site that need some tweaks. I'm the only developer. I do not know what files will be modified. I do not want to store untouched files in the repository. I want to store in repository (local and remote) only modified files.

Could you please describe or point to the optimal strategy to reach what I want?

Comment: I have to ask... why?

Comment: If you only want to checkin certain files, then `git add` only those.

Comment: This makes no sense... if you are trying to save space then just use git and it will compress and optimize the storage for you.

Comment: @PeeHaa I want to have a history of my job and do not store unnecessary for me files.

Comment: @Hogan Yes, space is one of the reasons. Unnecessary for me files can takes 99.9% of repository.

Comment: Are there only a few large files? Are they user generated? Do they follow a certain pattern/path?

Comment: @bcmcfc When i asked the question i kept in mind a Wordpress site. The main reason of my question is: i want to know what changes i made and do not track other files. Of course also i will use branches and commits for development.

Comment: Addition of wordpress makes it a very different question. Perhaps this question is of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372916/git-workflow-with-wordpress-localhost-to-live

Comment: @bcmcfc Thank you for your replies. You asked about the files and i provided you with an example. Yes, files have a structure, yes they can be large, yes they can be generated. But not dependent on that i dream to have a history only of files changed by me. And do it in a most optimal way.

Answer (score 4):

Initialise the repository with the entire site as is. Commit it.

Then you're free to make changes and commit those changes.

The way git stores changes it with changesets, it needs a base to work from in order to figure out what those changesets consist of.

You could potentially create patch files instead but you wouldn't need git for that.

Even though you're the only developer, in the long term for your own sanity and ability to maintain the project, you're better off with a full repository of the codebase. If you only have patches you have no context of what you were working on and will have a hard time in the future going back to work on it again.

Comment: Because this is the opposite of what OP was asking to do.

Comment: Sometimes they need pointing in the right direction when they don't know why what they're asking for will cause them problems down the line.

Comment: yes agree. Hence I asked clarification in the comment  section instead of jumping on it. As it currently stands it's not even trying to address the actual OP.

Comment: That's fair enough. For the sake of future googlers/searchers, it's important that they have all options available in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation of the method that I use for my dotfiles in my home directory; I want to keep my dotfiles version controlled, but I *don't* want to put my whole home directory in git, obviously.

First, create a git repository:  `git init .` in the directory that you want to manage.

Next, add a `.gitignore` that contains *everything*.  For example:  `echo '*' > .gitignore`.  I recommend that you `git add .gitignore && git commit -m"Adding .gitignore"`

Now you can `git add ...` and `git commit` any files that you change.  However, you *must* do this manually.  `git status` will not show you files that you've changed from their initial state (since they're ignored) and there is no mechanism to snapshot the directory at the point that we made a git repository and have git automatically notice that we made changes to the files.  (To do this, you would need to create a git repository the proper way.)

However, once a file *has* been added to your git repository, it is no longer ignored (`.gitignore` applies only to files that aren't yet in your repository), so once you've added a file, you *will* see when you continue to change it.