# Github (or other SCM) Tracking only specific files

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am working on the game mod and want to manage the work I am doing on some VCS, i.e. github. The work is done on several files accross several subfolders. Thus it would be logical to have an entire game as a project. But I don't want to upload the entire game to github. It would be ideal if it was possible to manage just the files which were changed. That way it would be also eas(ier) to share this project with anyone who is insterested.

So, basically what I want is:

1. the entire project on git locally
2. only upload to git hub the files that have changed or/and the ***specific files*** (as per TTT comments below) I want to push to remote repo.

I saw similar question here: [What is the best strategy to store in repository only changed files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365142/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-store-in-repository-only-changed-files)

.gitignore is an option, but feels quite cumbersome. And managing this manually kind of defeats the point of having it on github to start with.

Also, the above link was for the question asked 6 years ago.

Any new ideas for this solution?

Comment: Even though you specified "changed files", I suppose what you really want is "specific files". For example, you might add a new important file that you would want to push. I think most answers wouldn't make the distinction anyway, so it doesn't really matter, however, I was tempted to think up an answer that said something like this: "Work however you want, and when you're done, run script X which will make a new branch for you that only includes commits for files that were modified." I decided to suggest doing this manually instead in my answer, but I believe it could be automated...

Comment: To continue my previous comment, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72593685/184546) offers a mechanism that could serve for a guideline to achieve your goal. Basically you would work however you want, and then later, you could create a new branch that would strip out everything except the files you wish to keep, and that could be automated using rebase with an `-Xours` strategy, after forcing conflicts on all files you *don't* want to push. Maybe that would be helpful if you hadn't planned ahead, but since you predicted this need I think you'd be better off just maintaining 2 branches.

Comment: To make a long comment longer, my point is if you do in fact mean "specific files" instead of "changed files", then I think that would be a worthwhile edit. If someone did want to automate a fixup after the fact, using "changed files" would actually be easier than "some unknown set of files TBD". But I worry that wouldn't be exactly right if you happened to add even just one file that should be pushed. ;)

Comment: What you said makes perfect sense. Updated the title and edited description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the easiest way is to simply .gitignore everything except the files you would want to push, but you lose all the benefits of source control for everything else...

Although a little cumbersome, if you're willing to maintain two branches, this workflow would be pretty straight forward:

- A branch `branch-to-push` would contain commits that modify only the files you wish to push.
- A branch `do-not-push` would contain everything you wish to track locally.

You would work out of `do-not-push`, and anytime you wish to modify file(s) that you would want to push, switch to `branch-to-push`, commit the change, then switch back to `do-not-push` and merge in (or rebase onto) `branch-to-push`.

Comment: Excellent. This IMHO is a great work around!

Answer (score 0):

You can only `add` and `commit` files you want to be saved on Github. And other local files would be saved only on your computer

Comment: Sure, but 1) git will ask to add all of the files to the project as it will see that remote repo doesn't have the files checked in locally, so I would have to ignore the entire project and then manually add the files, which is not ideal 2) If I can find the solution, then I would prefer not to track the changes (or what have changed) manually and I will have to if I ignore the entire project to handle point 1)

Comment: Yes, many IDEs (ex. Jetbrains`) support handling what you want to track in very convenient way

Comment: IDEs support the standard git usage and provide graphical representation for it. What I want is customised git setup, which has to be done on the git side. Once that is done any IDE can be used to my convenience, but it is not what my question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Git by design *requires* that *every* commit contain *every file*.  If you don't want that, you don't want Git (nor Mercurial, etc).  Consider using an old file-oriented version control system such as RCS (though such systems are generally not distributed, and there's no convenient forge like GitHub for that).

Answer (score 0):

Git isn't really designed to do what you are asking here. If you commit files locally, then they will be uploaded to a remote repository (such as GitHub) when you do a `git push`. There is no way to selectively upload files that you are tracking with git.